# What is data-analytics-placement and data-analytics-link?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have found one source code, in that there are `data-analytics-placement` and `data-analytics-link`.
I can't find this thing on google too. I wanted to use this on my website but I don't know what's the mean of this function.

```
<div class="c-masthead__main" data-analytics-placement="navigation" style="background-image: url()">
    <div class="1-wrapper">
<a href="/" data-anylytics-link="home"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`data-analytics-placement` and `data-analytics-link` are custom [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attributes which you can later use in your CSS and JS to manipulate the DOM.

```css
div[data-analytics-placement='navigation'] {
  color: red;
}

a[data-anylytics-link='home'] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-masthead__main" data-analytics-placement="navigation" style="background-image: url()">
  <span>Target Navigation</span>
  <div class="1-wrapper">
    <a href="/" data-anylytics-link="home">Target Home</a>
  </div>
</div>
```